# How to deal in python with the xml files preceded by the TIME prefix in successive runs of SUMO

Tags: python, sumo

I want to get the results of a SUMO successive runs in CSV format directly by using python script (not by using the xml2csv tools and cmd). Due to the TIME prefix comes before the XML file, I don't know how to deal with this part of the code.
Here we want the run to show the results separately by using the time:
sumoCmd = [sumoBinary, "-c", "test4.sumocfg", "--tripinfo-output", "tripinfo.xml", "--output-prefix", " TIME"].
And here is where I must put the proper XML file name which is my question:
tree = ET.parse("myfile.xml")

Any help would be appreciated.
Best, Ali

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just find the file using glob e.g.:

```
import glob
tripinfos = glob.glob("*tripinfo.xml")
```

To get the latest you can use sorted:

```
latest = sorted(tripinfos)[-1]
tree = ET.parse(latest)
```